# Vulkan Setup - VS Code, MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, vulkan

I want to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=diXZ4Zj6VOs

(Vulkan SDK developement with C++, hoping to use my GPU with it to make some neat shaders)

But...

- I want to use **VS Code**, not Visual Studio
- I want to use **MSVC (v142)**, not mingw-w64 or mingw

---

What I have so far:

- **Windows** 64-bit OS, x64 processor, Intel i7-10510U CPU, Intel UHD Graphics iGPU, NVIDIA GeForce MX250 GPU
- **VS Code** with C++ extension
- **Visual Studio** 2019 with MSVC v142
- **Developer Command Prompt** for VS 2019 (opening VS Code from this allows C++ to be compiled from VS Code)
- **Vulkan** SDK 1.2.135.0
- **Project** in VS Code:

  ```
  > .vscode/
  \----> launch.json
  \----> tasks.json
  \----> c_cpp_properties.json
  > main.cpp
  ```

How can I go about doing this while being able to run main.cpp quickly and properly in VS Code?

Any neat ways to use launch.json, tasks.json, or c_cpp_properties.cpp is also welcomed.

Comment: Ok so I think I figured it out... I will test it out a bit before posting.

Comment: any luck with figuring it out? @lbrahim

Comment: I cannot remember but I think I did get somewhere... I have this project on pause atm on another laptop.

Comment: Tbh too much effort required to get something useful so I'm just sticking to Js for game development for now.